# Mysql table joining

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql tables **table 1 and table 2**. 

**Table 1** contain a field 'subjectcat' of type varchar that contain subject ids sepereated by commas( eg. 1,2,3). 

**Table 2** contain a field 'mark' of type float that contain student mark. I want to get the sum of marks from table 2 where subject ids are from table 1.

I have the query

```
  select t1.subjectcat, sum(t2.mark) 
  from table t1, table t2 
  where t2.subjectid in (t1.subjectcat).
```

but this query fails to give  correct sum marks, but gives the mark of only the first subject(subjectid).

How can I modify the query to get the correct result ?

Comment: Can you post the table structure?

Comment: Normalize your db schema and you won't have such problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` in `JOIN` to achieve your goal

```sql
SELECT t1.subjectcat, SUM(t2.mark) sum_mark
  FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t2.subjectid, t1.subjectcat) > 0
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c37e7/3)** demo

*Having said that I strongly encourage you to **normalize your db schema.***

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that it returns only one row because of aggregate SUM(). Try to put `GROUP BY t2.subjectid` at the end of your query if it solves your problem.